How is \$V_{DSsat}=V_{GS}- V_T\$ in an E-MOSFET?
In an electronics book by R. Boylestad, it is given that for VDG = VDS-VGS if VDS increases, for constant VGS, VGD decreases which means Drain is more positive than Gate and hence reduces the attractive forces on electrons and therby reducing n channel width. It obviously does not make sense to me as drain being relatively positive than Gate does not mean Gate's potential has dropped. So for me it is the more reverse bias at Drain that is causing channel to shrink (depletion region gets wider).  What is more irritating to me is that I can't get how He wrote VDSSat = VGS-VT? 


If you find time try to read this: http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/Applying%20a%20Drain%20Voltage%20to%20an%20NMOS%20Device.pdf

@greybeard i have edited and added that figure.

That looks 6.37 is like a depletion mode picture rather than a lotus of saturation levels

For saturation in a MOSFET, these two conditions must be satisfied:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{DS} &> V_T \\ \\
V_{DS} &> V_{GS} - V_T \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
The second of these relates to the special condition that you are concerned with:
$$ V_{DS(SAT)} = V_{GS} - V_T$$
The hint is the "\$=\$", as opposed to "\$>\$". This is a special case of saturation, where the transistor is saturated but sitting right on the cusp of entering the triode region, which would occur if \$V_{DS}\$ were to decrease any further.
I believe that the \$_{(SAT)}\$ qualifier signifies this specific state of saturation, right on that knife edge between triode and saturation, as opposed to the broader range of \$V_{DS}\$ upwards of \$V_{GS} - V_T\$. This special state lies on the dotted line in this graph, borrowed from another SE answer:


i dont have much knowledge from where did u get these relations as for me i just have conditions on VGS bieng greater than VT,so i am still unable to understand your point.

The textbook may confuse the reader when describing Depletion mode FETs and the more common Enhancement mode FETs that follow such as this answer.  That's why this answer confuses you

Are you confusing the "saturation mode" of a MOSFET with the "saturation mode" of a BJT? The terms are banana with that respect... Just thinking.

The vdsat condition is stated rather than explained. As noted the next figure is more relevant. But I don't have high hopes as the figure on this page omits details like the depletion region and has a peculiar shape for the channel.
I assume this is a book about circuits?? I would go elsewhere for a good explanation of mosfets.

Your reasoning about the shrinking channel width in an n-channel MOSFET is correct and your confusion is justified.
You have a right to be confused with the book describing and drawing the depletion mode on the same page referring a the plot of locus of the saturation curve shared by both Depletion & Enhancement mode FETs. This fault even propagates to different versions of his books.  (see snippet below)

For Depletion-mode MOSFETs when \$V_{GS}=0\$ they are normally conducting \$I_D=I_{DSS}\$.

The device will begin to "deplete" and reduce current when \$V_{GS}\$ is made more negative (n-channel) or positive (p-channel).


For Enhancement-mode MOSFETs when |\$V_{GS}|\$ less than  |\$V_T\$|, they are considered "off"  with \$I_D=0\$ mA.

Enhancement-mode MOSFETs require a \$V_{GS}\$ than the threshold to conduct or begin to turn "on" and enter saturation.
The \$V_{DS\text{(sat)}}\$  is the minimum voltage
needed across the drain and source to maintain the MOSFET in the
saturation region.



In both types, \$V_{DS\text{(sat)}}\$ is determined by the difference between \$V_{GS}\$ and \$V_{TH}\$, but the overall behaviour of the MOSFET concerning \$V_{GS}\$ and \$V_{DS}\$ differs based on whether the device is normally off (enhancement-mode) or normally on (depletion-mode).
  Source p.404  https://mohamadramdhani.staff.telkomuniversity.ac.id/files/2016/08/Electronic-Devices-and-Circuit-Theory-11th-Edition-Ebook.pdf
Take 2 # (To explain the linear relationship, graphically)
The Enhancement Mode MOSFET curves (normally shown for the positive Nch parts), where there is a quadratic equation for $$I_{DS}=\dfrac{\beta}{2}({V_{GS}-V_T)}^2$$
where:
•   \$I_{DS}~~~~~~~~~~\$ : Drain current
•   \$β=μ_nC_{ox}\frac{W}{L}~~~\$ :Transconductance parameter
•   \$V_{GS}~~~~~~~~~~\$ : Gate-to-source voltage
•   \$V_T~~~~~~~~~~~~\$ :   Threshold voltage
The question concerns the bound of "FET saturation" where this equation holds true and the follow-on linear relationship;
\$V_{DS\text{(sat)}}=V_{GS}-V_T~~~~~~~~\$  or    \$~~~~~~~~~V_{GS}=V_{DS\text{(sat)}}+V_T\$  then combined with a above;
$$I_{DS}=\dfrac{\beta}{2}({V_{DS}})^2$$

The requirement for these plots is \$R_D = 0R\$, the gate voltage \$V_{GS}\$ equals the output \$V_{DS}+V_T\$ (effectively, the drain is directly connected to the supply). The quadratic locus relationship simplifies to:
\$I_{DS} >= \frac{\beta}{2} (V_{DS}=V_{GS})^2\$
Because the current is linear with transconductance and the load is 0 Ohms and the plot is independent of Vds above the saturation threshold then the Rdson is fixed with \$R_{DSon} = V_{ds/Id}\$   Raising Vds then does not increase the current but requires a Rd=0.
The transconductance is linear \$V_{DS(sat)} >= V_{GS} - V_T\$, and \$V_{GS}\$ is swept here but stepped et by the  sine wave (2Vpp superimposed on the DC bias) the drain current is flat for a fixed Vgs.

Here’s a more structured explanation

MOSFET Operation Curve Description:


The MOSFET curves for an enhancement-mode n-channel MOSFET show the quadratic relationship: \$I_{DS} = \frac{\beta}{2} (V_{GS} - V_T)^2\$
The saturation boundary is defined as: \$V_{DS(sat)} = V_{GS} - V_T\$


Simulation Setup:


The circuit includes a sine wave (2Vpp) applied to \$V_{GS}\$ with a DC sweep from 0V to 5V, while \$R_D = 0\$.
The resulting curves display the quadratic dependence of \$I_{DS}\$ on \$V_{DS}\$ in saturation.


Observations:


In the saturation region, \$I_{DS}\$ depends solely on \$V_{GS}\$, as \$V_{DS} > V_{DS(sat)} \$ .
The relationship \$I_{DS} = \frac{\beta}{2} (V_{DS})^2\$ is valid due to the applied conditions \$R_D = 0\$.


@DAS at the most i can agree on the said relation bieng like a proportionality but how is it precisely equal to the difference confuses me?Any philosphy that can help ne get how is Vdssat equal to the given difference?
